# My Julia is broken???? When I use RCall it pops up and gives me the intro, then i cant type into the console

Tags: r, statistics, julia

The title says it all. I'm not sure what to do. I tried to download a package in R through Julia and I think it's all broken now (when I try to use RCall. Is there anything I can do? I've found nothing on the internet about it.

```
               _
   _       _ _(_)_     |  Documentation: https://docs.julialang.org
  (_)     | (_) (_)    |
   _ _   _| |_  __ _   |  Type "?" for help, "]?" for Pkg help.
  | | | | | | |/ _` |  |
  | | |_| | | | (_| |  |  Version 1.6.3 (2021-09-23)
 _/ |\__'_|_|_|\__'_|  |  Official https://julialang.org/ release
|__/                   |

julia> using RCall

R version 4.0.0 (2020-04-24) -- "Arbor Day"
Copyright (C) 2020 The R Foundation for Statistical Computing
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)

R is free software and comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY.
You are welcome to redistribute it under certain conditions.
Type 'license()' or 'licence()' for distribution details.

R is a collaborative project with many contributors.
Type 'contributors()' for more information and
'citation()' on how to cite R or R packages in publications.

Type 'demo()' for some demos, 'help()' for on-line help, or
'help.start()' for an HTML browser interface to help.
Type 'q()' to quit R.
```

Usually I would see

```
julia>
```

but I do not...

Comment: I also just updated R on my computer to a new version 4.1.2, could that be the problem?

Comment: While you do have to explicitly specify the R installation's directory and build (not re-add!) RCall to use it (https://juliainterop.github.io/RCall.jl/stable/installation/), I'm not sure if that's the cause of the REPL issue here. Like if RCall is just stuck failing to find the old v4.0.0, then I wouldn't expect that v4.0.0 intro to be printed...